# Is it possible to create internal passthrough network load balancer with zonal NEGs in GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, internal-load-balancer

I am trying to migrate ingress-controller based ingress which uses internal load balancer with managed instance group as backend to istio based load balancer which uses `Service` object and will spawn an ILB with unmanaged instance group as backend, I want an L4 load balancer. However, that setup is apparently not allowed in GKE as worker nodes can only belong to at most 1 load-balanced instance group.

Now, I am trying to find a way to work around that restriction, i.e. spawning istio gateway using an internal passthrough load balancer (L4) and using zonal NEGs as backend. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: try refering this : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing

Comment: This [guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/setting-up-internal-zonal-neg) will show you how to deploy an internal passthrough Network Load Balancer with zonal network endpoint group backends.

Comment: Thanks @Srividya but this is for VMs, I need for GKE cluster